# DCE RPC - Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, rpc, dce

I have to check a Profinet Network in order to get all the components. I could ask them via NSMP, or DCP, but I need the UUID to after that executing functions via RPC.

The problem is that, there was a function named LookUpBegin(next and stop) that did the work for Windows NT, but is unsupported after Vista OS. Now I have seen that there has to be something [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc244264.aspx) but I have not been able to find what it is, where it is located...

Have you had any experience with DCE-RPC in C++?
Best way? Any sample? whatever.

Another question is: I have to execute functions in a device server that I do not know. Is there any function of RPC that allows to execute a function giving an id or similar and a string? A kind of socket that you send to the server and if it was well coded the server would execute something. Because I have been able to sniff the traces via Wireshark. So I could know some part of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: make your own packets and send them via sockets. Wireshark can help.